# Call rake task on routes.rb update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Using `rails 4.2.1`.

I want to call a `rake` task on every `config/routes.rb` file save.  How would I go about doing this?

Note: the `rake` task does require the `rails` environment. i.e. it's of the `task :task_name => :environment do #...` nature.

Comment: using something like `guard` I guess

Comment: how the going with the issue?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Not solved yet.  I always thought that `rails` itself detects a change to the `routes.rb` file and runs something like `Rails.application.reload_routes!`.  I want to find the function that calls `reload_routes!` and extend it to also run my `rake` task.  No luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into [filewatcher](https://github.com/thomasfl/filewatcher#ruby-api) gem.

You can define actions to be taken depending on what changes are made to specified file (or directory):

```
require 'filewatcher'

FileWatcher.new("config/routes.rb").watch() do |filename, event|
  if(event == :changed)
    your_rake_task
  end
  if(event == :delete)
    # ...
  end
  if(event == :new)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In `rails 4.2.1`

```
# development.rb
require 'rake'
Rails.application.configure do
#...
  Rails.application.load_tasks
  # code executes on routes change
  ActionDispatch::Reloader.to_prepare do
    Rails.application.reload_routes!

    if JsRoutes.assert_usable_configuration!
      Rake::Task['js_routes:generate'].reenable
      Rake::Task['js_routes:generate'].invoke
    end
  end
#...
end
```

Based off of https://stackoverflow.com/a/27046271/749477